# How can I properly label each subsection in the appendix?

Tags: appendix

I want to reference different subsections in my appendix in the main body of my document. I have used `\label{}` after each subsection begnning, but then, when I use `\ref{thatlabel}` is simple gives me a number that does not refer to my subsection in the appendix.

My appendix:

```
\appendix

\section*{Appendix 4}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix 4}


In our thesis, we have used extensively the programming language Python to create, prepare and analyze our data set. This appendix contains the most important scripts we have used. Each script is accompanied by a short description that explains the main features and the results it provides.
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{5.1 Downloading the .zip files containing the EDGAR logs}
\subsection*{4.1 Downloading the .zip files containing the EDGAR logs}
\label{Appendix.DownloadingZipFiles}


To download the .zip files, which we use for calculating the SBP scores, from the Edgar website, we used the "Logfile List" available here: https://www.sec.gov/dera/data/edgar-log-file-data-set.html. The file contains links to each individual .zip.

\lstinputlisting[language=Python]{./Code/get_zip_files.py}

\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{4.2 Downloading the form types files}
\subsection*{4.2 Downloading the form types files}
\label{Appendix.DownloadingFormTypes}

We need to have a database with the form types corresponding to each accession number. This allows us to select only the relevant form types for the analysis. The code below, downloads those form types from the Edgar' master index.

\lstinputlisting[language=Python]{./Code/get_form_files.py}

\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{4.3 Calculation of the Annual Search Fractions}
\label{Appendix4.1:AnnualSearchFrac}
\subsection*{4.3 Calculation of the Annual search fractions}


The following script is one the largest and most complex script we have used. It calculates the ASF scores for the SBP selection scheme. 

\lstinputlisting[language=Python]{./Code/SBP_frac_theis.py}

\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{4.4 Creation of the trailing accounts for our database}
\subsection*{4.4 Creation of the trailing accounts for our database}
\label{Appendix.CreatingTrailingAccounts}

The script takes the raw quarterly fundamentals from WRDS. We downloaded the quarterly fundamentals for the firms belonging to the S\&P1500 index from Compustat/North America - Annual Updates/Fundamentals Quarterly/ and transformed them into the trailing accounting data that we use in our analysis.

\lstinputlisting[language=Python]{./Code/read_csv.py}
\break

\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{5.5 Creation of the peer groups based on SBP}
\subsection*{4.5 Creation of the peer groups based on SBP}
\label{Appendix.CreatingPeerGroupsSBP}

The code below, takes the 3 inputs: the trailing accounts database, the index constituents and the annual search fractions. Using these 3 inputs, the it can create peer groups of different sizes.

\lstinputlisting[language=Python]{./Code/SBP_peer_groups.py}

\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{4.6 Creation of the peer groups based on GICS}
\subsection*{4.6 Creation of the peer groups based on GICS}
\label{Appendix.CreatingPeerGroupsGICS}
```

For example, if I try to reference `\label{Appendix.DownloadingZipFiles}` it displays number 7. Is there a proper way to reference the subsections in the appendix? Thank you!

Comment: why do you use `\section*{Appendix 4}` and not `\section{Appendix}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a `\section*` or `\subsection*` command, the internal label value is not set. This is done because a `(sub)section*` does not have a number, so it cannot be referred to by this number. Instead, the last known number is used in case the code contains a `\label` command, which is obviously wrong. In the case of the current question the number is added manually, so it can be referenced, but this requires that the internal label value is also set manually.

In the MWE below a new command `\apxsub` is defined as a replacement for `\subsection`. This new command has three arguments: the number, the title, and the reference identifier. The command creates a `\subsection*`, adds a contents line, sets the internal `\@currentlabel` value and creates the label. The command is enclosed in `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` because there is an at symbol (`@`) in `\@currentlabel`, which means that this macro is not accessible unless the `@` character is treated as a normal character, which is what `\makeatletter` does. The counterpart `\makeatother` restores the special status of the `@` character afterwards.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\apxsub}[3]{%
\subsection*{#1 #2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1 #2}
\def\@currentlabel{#1}%
\label{#3}%
}
\makeatother

\tableofcontents
\section{Normal section}
See also subsection \ref{sec:sub41} in the appendix.
\appendix
\section*{Appendix 4}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix 4}

\apxsub{4.1}{Downloading}{sec:sub41}
Some text

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

However, this issue looks like an example of what is called an X-Y problem on Stack Exchange websites: you attempt to solve problem X with solution Y, there are problems with Y and you ask about those, while a better approach would be to address X. In this case problem X is that you don't like the default appearance of Appendix sections, i.e. `A Some Title`, `B Some other title` etc. The attempt to solve this problem is by using starred sections and subsections, with the additional issue that such sections cannot be referenced. Instead, a better solution would be to change the appearance of appendix titles and use regular (non-starred) sections, which are automatically included in the TOC and which can be referenced.

The `appendix` package can partly help with this, it provides options to put the word *Appendix* (or some other word) in front of the section title. To change the numbering from letters to digits you can redefine the numbering macro yourself. Note that this approach does not use the `\appendix` switch but instead an environment `\begin{appendices}\end{appendices}`.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Normal section}
See also subsection \ref{sec:sub41} in the appendix.
\begin{appendices}
\setcounter{section}{3} % skip first three appendices
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} % redefine section numbering from letters to digits
\section{}
\subsection{Downloading}
\label{sec:sub41}
Some text
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Results are the same as above.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and patience. I totally agree with you that my question is a X-Y problem. Everything works now as I expected and no errors were raised.